# Layout Edtior not showing Toolbar - NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, graphical-layout-editor

All is working fine on phones and in emulator, but I can't use the Layout Editor in Android Studio because I get following error:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

- android support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

The same I get with the ConstraintLayout in another layout.

**Exception Details:**

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:235)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:211)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Image how it looks like:**
[image]

**My Layout XML for the Toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/toolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="?attr/toolbarPopupTheme"/>
```

**Gradle for the "Support Library":**

```
// Support Library  
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'

I use Android Studio Version **3.0.1**!

What have I already done and found in other StackOverflow threads:
- Invalid Caches and Restart
- Clean Project and Rebuild Project
- Themes I used change from parent "Theme.AppCompat" to "Base.Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: In the meantime I have also added an Issue at the Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71641021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
It seems the Layout Editor has some troubles if you have **to much** attributes in one `<declare-stylable>` tag defined in your **attr.xml**!

**Solution:**
I have **49** attributes in one `<declare-stylable>` tag.
If I remove **5** attributes, so I have **45**, the Layout Editor is working.

I have also added an Issue on the Google Issue Tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71641021

**UPDATE from Google Issue:**
This has been fixed for the Android Studio 3.1 release.